# How can I start, pause and resume my threads? (by extending thread from classes)

Tags: java, multithreading

Essentially, what I want to do is start all my threads, pause them all, then resume them all, using the multithreading approach. I am just looking for a simple solution to this. I'm not sure if I have to use a timer or what. Right now when I run it, the threads are like being executed in random order (I guess the PC is just randomly picking which ones it wants to run at a certain time).

```
class ChoppingThread extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        for(int j=40;j!=0;j-=10)
            System.out.println("Chopping vegetables...("+j+" seconds left)");
    }   
 }
class MixingThread extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        for(int k=60;k!=0;k-=10)
            System.out.println("Mixing sauces...("+k+" seconds left)");
    }
}
class TenderizingThread extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        for(int j=50;j!=0;j-=10)
            System.out.println("Tenderizing meat...("+j+" seconds left)");
    }
}
class MultiThreadTasking
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        ChoppingThread ct = new ChoppingThread();
        MixingThread mt = new MixingThread();
        TenderizingThread tt = new TenderizingThread();

        System.out.println("\nWelcome to the busy kitchen.");
        //putting threads into ready state
        ct.start();
        mt.start();
        tt.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need some kind state flag and monitor lock. While running, you'll need to check for changes in state and take appropriate actions. Also, you shouldn't need to extend from Thread, Runnable would be a better and more flexible choice

Comment: Can you simplify that? I only have a basic understanding of Java. (This is for an assignment.) I just picked up programming again (it has been a while and I don't think I covered this the first time around).

Comment: What you need is synchronization.

Comment: what does that even mean? do i need like a timer? we didn't cover how to use those yet...

Comment: Check [here](http://www.slideshare.net/caswenson/learning-java-3-threads-and-synchronization).

Comment: "Simple" is a relative statement

Comment: Like, in the easiest way possible.

Comment: If this really is an assignment for an entry-level java class, then talk to your "teacher". Java Concurrency, especially when done properly, is not for the faint of heart and definitely not entry-level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably other ways to achieve the same result, but this is the simplest I can come up with off the top of my head (I know, sad isn't it)...

Basically, this is a special `Runnable` with some additional management functionality.

This basically contains a state flag that indicates the state of the task and a monitor lock

```
public class ThreadFun {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyTask task = new MyTask();
    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.start();
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
    task.pauseTask();
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
    task.resumeTask();
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
    task.stopTask();
  }

  public enum TaskState {

    Running,
    Stopped,
    Paused

  }

  public static class MyTask implements Runnable {

    private static final Object PAUSED_LOCK = new Object();

    private volatile TaskState state = TaskState.Running;

    public void pauseTask() {
      if (state == TaskState.Running) {
        System.out.println("Paused...");
        state = TaskState.Paused;
      }
    }

    public void resumeTask() {
      if (state == TaskState.Paused) {
        state = TaskState.Running;
        synchronized (PAUSED_LOCK) {
          PAUSED_LOCK.notifyAll();
        }
        System.out.println("Resumed...");
      }
    }

    public void stopTask() {
      if (state == TaskState.Running || state == TaskState.Paused) {
        state = TaskState.Stopped;
        System.out.println("Stopped...");
      }
    }

    public boolean isStopped() {
      return state == TaskState.Stopped;
    }

    public boolean isPaused() {
      return state == TaskState.Paused;
    }

    protected void doPause() {
      synchronized (PAUSED_LOCK) {
        while (isPaused()) {
          try {
            PAUSED_LOCK.wait();
          } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          }
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

      int index = 0;
      while (!isStopped() && index < 1000) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(25);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        doPause();
        index++;
        System.out.println(index);
      }
      stopTask(); // Make sure the task is marked as begin stopped ;)

    }

  }
}
```

The main criteria is you will need to pool `isStopped` and `doPause` at appropriate points to ensure that they are begin implemented as required...

Answer (score 2):

To coordinate them use a [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

To launch them all at the same time use a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Google the two classes above for many examples and explanations.

To fully understand what is happening read the [Java Concurrency In Practice](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/) [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601).

Comment: Is there an easy way to do this? I think this is suppose to be a fairly simple assignment so I'm just looking for a simple solution.

Comment: +1 I like the idea of the `CyclicBarrier`, this does mean (and I think you're right to assume this) that the OP wants to pause all the threads at once (and not have the ability to do each one individual or as groups)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, yup that's what I thought from the question.

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer, concurrent code can be complicated when doing things like coordinating or sharing state. MadProgrammer's answer will give you a start on understanding locks (aka mutex, monitor) which require lots of keywords such `volatile` and `synchronized`, while my answer will direct you to higher level constructs.  I would start with the example MadProgrammer lists and read up on the bits that are new to you, then look at the `java.util.concurrent` classes. Either way multi-threading will always seem slightly _voodoo_ unless you understand the theory (the JCIP book is very good).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can accomplish this by using [`Object.wait`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) and [`Thread.interrupt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29).

`Object.wait` blocks until `notify` is called. So

```
private boolean paused;
private Object waitObject;
...
public void run() {
    for ... {
        if (this.paused) { this.waitObject.wait(); }
    ...

public void pause() { this.paused = true; }
public void resume() { this.paused = false; this.waitObject.notify(); }
```

Then you can call `pause` to pause the thread.

`Thread.interrupt` can help with stopping.

```
private boolean paused;
...
public void run() {
    for ... {
        // interrupted() is different from interrupt()!
        if (this.iterrupted()) { break; }
    ...
```

To stop it, you would call `interrupt()` from another thread.

This is the basic idea, but there's a lot of details to worry about here. For example, `wait` can throw an `InterruptedException` you'll need to handle. Also, `wait` is not guaranteed to return only after a `notify`. It *can* return randomly. Here is a pair of tutorials:

- Wait: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html
- Interrupt: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html